# Warmup requests for PHP 7.2?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-php

The current documentation of AppEngine for PHP 7.2 does not mention warmup requests. While I can configure some warmup settings, I cannot specify a specific handler.

app.yaml excerpt:

```
# url handlers
handlers:

- url: /_ah/warmup
  script: warmup.php
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: auto


# run url request on startup
inbound_services:
- warmup
```

Error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: script field for handler '/_ah/warmup' must be set to 'auto' for runtime php72.

How can I securely receive warmup requests now?

Comment: The warmup requests for PHP 7.2 are specified in [Configuring Warmup Requests to Improve Performance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/configuring-warmup-requests), but your description (which follows the documentation) appears to suggest something may actually be wrong in the documentation.